# Free cash Point of Sale (PoS) software sought

Tags: gratis, open-source, ubuntu

Is there a free cash Point of Sale software (PoS) for **Ubuntu**?

It should work in **German**. It's for a climbing hall: We sell **individual entries** and **memberships**, we have a little **restaurant** and a **small shop** in the shop. We also want to have a **database of our customers with documents** (insurance policies, etc.).

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: Added more info.

Comment: That's better already. Not exactly my area of expertise (I don't know any POS), but it might help if you could list your requirements more explicit: what features do you need, which ones would be "nice to have" (but not absolutely required), and whether there's anything you absolutely don't want to be in the software.